# Identify this plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, planting, weeds

I saw this plant on the street. It’s growing where weeds are supposed to grow, but it has big green leaves so I’m wondering what it is. I’ve never seen a plant like this grow on a sidewalk ledge.

I live in the Caribbean, so this gets tons of sun, it grows in a space where weeds grow, and it only receives rainwater.

Can it grow in a pot on a rooftop?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a member of the *Brassica* (cabbage) family, but I am not sure what species.

Comment: if you break a leaf is there white sap?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just looked today and it does have white sap.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tropical milkweed (calotropis). You can cut off a branch, root it in water, dip in rooting hormone and plant in sandy soil. We have three right now rooting. It is a weed so you could also dig it up and pot it (great for butterflies).

Answer (score 1):

Which part of the Caribbean? It looks like *Tectona grandis* aka Teak. More pictures would make it easier to identify. You can try posting it to iNaturalist where I'm sure tons of experts wouldn't mind helping you out